# How to subset phyloseq object to show overlapping ASVs from two sample types

Tags: r, phyloseq

I have a phyloseq object made called "shared"

```
    phyloseq-class experiment-level object
otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 3823 taxa and 64 samples ]
sample_data() Sample Data:       [ 64 samples by 17 sample variables ]
tax_table()   Taxonomy Table:    [ 3823 taxa by 12 taxonomic ranks ]
```

and I am trying to make a new phyoloseq object from the interesction of the shared ASVs between the two sample types.

basically, I want a phyloseq object of the green part of this Venn diagram.

[Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQJT6.png).

I made this plot from the "MicEco" package and have not found a way to access that interestion from it.

```
library("MicEco")
venn<-ps_venn(shared,"sample_type", quantities = list(type=c("percent","counts"), font = 2), labels = list(cex = 2), col = "black", fill = c("red","yellow","green"))
venn
```

Answer (score 0):

Let there be OTUs 1 called 1 and 2 but only the first one appears in both sample groups BL and SC. Then you can create a phyloseq object containing only the selected OTU and its abundance in all samples like this:

```r
library(phyloseq)
#> Creating a generic function for 'nrow' from package 'base' in package 'biomformat'
#> Creating a generic function for 'ncol' from package 'base' in package 'biomformat'
#> Creating a generic function for 'rownames' from package 'base' in package 'biomformat'
#> Creating a generic function for 'colnames' from package 'base' in package 'biomformat'
library(tidyverse)

otus <- tribble(
  ~otu_id, ~s1, ~s2, ~s3,
  1, 10, 10, 20,
  2, 5, 5, 0
)

samples <- tribble(
  ~sample_id, ~group,
  "s1", "BL",
  "s2", "BL",
  "s3", "SC"
)

selected_otus <-
  otus %>%
  pivot_longer(-otu_id, names_to = "sample_id", values_to = "abundance") %>%
  left_join(samples) %>%
  group_by(otu_id, group) %>%
  summarise(abundance = sum(abundance)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = abundance) %>%
  # must be found in both sample groups
  filter(BL > 0 & SC > 0) %>%
  pull(otu_id) %>%
  unique()
#> Joining, by = "sample_id"
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'otu_id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
selected_otus
#> [1] 1

phy <- phyloseq(
  otus %>%
    filter(otu_id %in% selected_otus) %>%
    column_to_rownames("otu_id") %>%
    otu_table(taxa_are_rows = TRUE),
  samples %>%
    column_to_rownames("sample_id") %>%
    sample_data()
)
phy
#> phyloseq-class experiment-level object
#> otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 1 taxa and 3 samples ]
#> sample_data() Sample Data:       [ 3 samples by 1 sample variables ]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>